# Is there a valid reason to code a false boolean as "Boolean.FALSE" in java?

Tags: java

So code reviewers are complaining about code like this:

```
boolean myFlag = false;
```

They are saying it should be:

```
boolean myFlag = Boolean.FALSE;
```

Is this just some fetish with not using keywords or is there a valid reason to do this?

Comment: Tell your code reviewers to go read up on autoboxing.

Comment: I would say it's a fetish. However, if the coding standards used specify that you should use Boolean.FALSE, you should use that, whether you like it or not, and whether it's sane or not.

Comment: I'd suggest to change the question title as it is not very clear what you are talking...

Comment: "if the coding standards used specify that you should use [...], you should use that... whether it's sane or not". I disagree. If you find the standard odd, you should seek to have a conversation about it, and question the reviewers, to be able to learn the reason for the standard and possibly discuss it. You as the reviewee might learn something new or you might be able to correct someone else's misunderstanding. But blindly following along does neither of these things. However, if they insist upon following a standard that makes no sense after discussion, then that is another subject.

Comment: there is a (valid?) reason: for increasing readability (if missing your glasses) [:-)

Comment: `false` and `true` are literals, not keywords. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.9 "The boolean type has two values, represented by the literals true and false, formed from ASCII letters."

Comment: It does make about as much sense as `private static final int ONE = 0;`.

Comment: @Tom, that may be useful to pascal developers moving to java

Comment: @Sweko, *However, if the coding standards used specify that you should use Boolean.FALSE, you should use that, whether you like it or not...*, I'd rather quit multiple times than doing something inherently retarded.

Comment: @Rocky, nice one, but still I see no way to use the constant (I did love pascal and delphi)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No, that's completely pointless. It would make sense to use:

```
// Note capital B
Boolean myFlag = Boolean.FALSE;
```

to avoid the call to `Boolean.valueOf` (autoboxing) but in your code there *is* no boxing, and their suggestion introduces an unnecessary *unboxing* operation.

As ever though, if someone suggests something and you don't understand why, your first port of call should be *asking them*.

Comment: Additionally, if you have boolean myFlag = false;, you should just use boolean myFlag;

Comment: @Danail: Not if it's a local variable.

Comment: Yes, this was my thought too.  I don't know if the compiler would automatically unbox it so that it would be converted but I figured there was no real point to it.  Also the code standards doc says nothing about it, so I will just argue back with them that it's pointless.

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing wrong with using keyword false.  In fact, in your code you'd be silly to use Boolean.False since there is an implicit auto unboxing that has to occur to assign it to your primitive field/variable (Boolean.False is a Boolean and not a boolean).

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make much sense as a complaint since `Boolean.FALSE` is unboxed to `false` anyway. But perhaps ask the people telling you to change the code why?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of one reason, *if you really want to dig for a possible reason*:

In an IDE like *Eclipse*, you can right-click `FALSE` (in `Boolean.FALSE`) and select *Open Call Hierarchy* or *References > (option)*. You can't do that with the literal `false`. But I don't know how useful finding all references of `Boolean.FALSE` will be in your development cycles.

**Curiously,** when I searched for references of `FALSE`, it was found littered all over the Java core (JDK/JRE) source code! Whether we want to use it or not, one thing is for sure, the guys who coded and maintain Java are using it heavily.

As per other answers, it's otherwise unnecessary and you can just use the literal `false`, especially if performance is important - avoiding the unboxing overhead. Code reviews must prioritize optimized readable/adequately-commented code over unoptimized readable code.